# How to setup HTTP basic auth for apache vhost running Laravel

Tags: laravel, apache, vhosts

I am trying to set up HTTP basic auth for the Laravel app in apache `vhost` but it is not working.

It keeps asking for a password after each request made

This is my current `vhost` content for the site and at the moment it is not doing anything. Any help is appreciated

```
ServerAdmin admin@my-site.com
ServerName demo.my-site.com
ServerAlias www.my-site.com
DocumentRoot /var/www/demos/my-site/client/public

<Directory "/var/www/demos/my-site/client">
    Options +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews +Indexes
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all

    AuthType Basic
    AuthName "Protected Area! Please login!"
    AuthUserFile /var/www/.htpasswd
    Require valid-user
</Directory>
```

Comment: You can use Laravel basic authentication: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/authentication#http-basic-authentication

Comment: Thing is I do not want to use that. I want to use vhost config for it

Answer (score 1):

You need to handle it through .htaccess in your root folder. Remove the .. from the vhost.

RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} ^(.+)$
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to do:

Put your project into a xampp > your_project,
browse localhost/your_project.